# How can I unwrap t.co links via an api to display the unshortened url?

Tags: php, twitter

If I have a Twitter t.co link, how can I unshorten it in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple example:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://t.co/...");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$yy = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$w = explode("\n",$yy);
$real_url = substr($w[3],10); # the fourth line is "Location: http://..."
echo $real_url;
```

Comment: What if the headers don't always come in the same order? The fourth line might not always be the Location: header.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) (with the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option) to fetch the URL's headers and look for the `Location:` header.

Comment: The redirect might not always be done with a Location: HTTP header, sometimes redirects are done using <meta> tags or <script> tags in the HTML body.

Comment: @JonathonHill The question was about t.co specifically, which does use a Location header.

Comment: That is true. I guess I was thinking that it is possible that they could change how their URL shortening service works at some point, although probably not likely.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` with `curl_getinfo()`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10661246/168815