# Change tiny urls to expanded url inside tweet

Tags: url, twitter, tinyurl

I am getting Twitter tweets in my website using v1.1 user timeline API, but the problem is the URLs tweeted are displaying in short form like t.co... format.

Now I want to display expanded URL instead of tiny URLs, so how can I can do this? Please give me a solution.

Note: I referred Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1, this questions in stackoverflow for getting tweets.

Comment: That last sentence melts my brain. What do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find where a t.co link goes to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500721/find-where-a-t-co-link-goes-to)